# Serving same content in same ip address with different domain names

Tags: linux, apache

An Apache web server for the domain “www.abc.lk” is configured and hosted in a hosting server with the IP address 192.168.2.105. Another domain called “www.def.lk” should also be configured with the same content without any duplication. Explain the configuration of the Apache server with name-based virtual hosting for the above requirement?

Comment: What is the intent of your problem? And, what is the actual problem?

Comment: I want to know how to do the name based virtual hosting for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure two virtual host with same DocumentRoot but different ServerNames

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

```perl
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.abc.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.123.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I didn't have clear idea about your answer, Could you plz give me the full answer?

Comment: This kind of configuration is usually intended to be used to running different domains with same apache http server. But, as you requested, both domains should serve same content. In order to achieve that, we're configuring same DocumentRoot for both VirtualHosts.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use www.abc.lk as ServerName and www.def.lk as ServerAlias in your vhost configuration ?

And of course be sure that both DNS point to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use (I think this link lays out all of the solutions or possibilities):
https://realtechtalk.com/Apache_Vhost_HowTo_Serve_Same_Content_using_a_different_domain_and_IP-1730-articles

Here is another way of doing it that is more simple than symlinking or duplicating content between vhosts:

This would be in your vhost.conf

```
ServerName differentdomain.com
ServerAlias www.differentdomain.com
ProxyPass / http://yourmainsite.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://yourmainsite.com/
```